# Iphone app using json parsing

Tags: iphone, ios4, uiview, uitableview, json

I have a question to do please!

I've been reading about how to create a iPhone app, what I need to do is parse some json structure.

I have the names of some products which will be displayed in a list then, when you click on each product you'll be redirected to the gallery of that product.. all this will have a database online!

Now, I've been trying to do this by using some sample codes, but I come at one point where I get stuck..

My question for you, if possible please, is to ask , **How do i start this?** I mean, should **I start with using a View based App, Tabbed app? Empty application?**

**How do I search in google**, with which key words about parsing json structure in order for them to act as a menu, I mean once you click the product the gallery should appear?

**What I need is just some keywords**... not any solution or anything else!
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start by taking View based App. In this type of app your a root view will already be added to your window. You can add a navigation Controller later... if you need any further assistance..feel free to ask!!

Comment: Hey thanks for replying :)
So let me grab the logic please! I create a View based app, then i Parse the json file as a Navigation controller?

Comment: No navigation controller is the top bar of the view.We use it for navigating between different views. You will have to do your JSON parsing in the view itself e.g. "ViewController.m"

Comment: Just one last stupid question , how do i parse the json array , i mean, once i do a http request, i get the array, i should create a view for each of the products? i mean, i need to parse the json, e.g i have the products listed, once i click on each product a image gallery opens. i need to create another view for this? :/

Comment: Have you got the array after parsing?? If yes and if you want to show all the products list, you can use a UITableView on the same view.

Comment: If you want to show the pictures on click of each taBLEview cell, then you will have to use a new view on iphone.

Comment: Ok, perfect, i'm building up the story now, i parse the json array, i use the UITableView, then, after i click on the product? what do i need to use in order to bring the photo gallery of each product? I mean i'll use even here json parsing for the images...

Comment: Then you need to pass the selected cell value to another view and show the image on an imageview there..

Comment: Thank you :) , you were a great help for me! All this people replying , most of them are from India! I need to go to India ASAP! :D, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Keywords for JSON:

1. parse json iphone
2. json parser for iphone
3. json skd iphone

Links to JSON [tutorial](http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-json-over-http-on-the-iphone/), [skd](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit/zipball/master) and example [project](https://github.com/dcgrigsby/luckynumbers/zipball/master).

Link to web application [tutorial](http://gigaom.com/apple/how-to-create-an-iphone-web-app/).

Link to web app using HTML5 [tutorial](http://sixrevisions.com/web-development/html5-iphone-app/).

Comment: Thanks Teodor, well i understand , i've searched before with this keywords, but i need something more specific , like use the json array generated as navigation controller..

Comment: Speak English, please: what does it mean "the json array generated as navigation controller"?

Comment: I'm sorry, i have problems with english anyways.. so , what i'm trying to do is, parse a json array using a http request, and each of this json items will be used as a button, there wil be the list like: Peugeot, Benz, Fiat, Ferrari etc and when you click on this opens the gallery of photos for each of them. in principle it has to be a simple thing. i'm just new!

Comment: ok, post a link to your json, or post the json string itself (no need to post all of it, if it's huge)

Comment: well, the json will be something like this:
Product1-Image1/Image2/Image3    Product2-Image1/image2/Image3... etc etc...

Comment: ... a perfect json example... very constructive... it looks like you wanna help yourself...

Comment: well, i'm trying to learn, i know i am not even at the beginning, i'm not even at level 0. I'm trying to understand! :/

Comment: ok, how do you get that json? do you get it via an URL? if so, launch that url into your preferred web browser, get the json and post it to see what are you working with. how can we help you if we do not know what json structure are you working with? Just in case you did not know: a good answer proceeds a well asked question.